# Viewing ActiveRecord model fields in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I'm new to Ruby and I come from a C# background so apologies if this is very basic. I'm navigating around a large Rails project and looking at the model (ActiveRecord) classes. I want to be able to easily see all of the fields of a class so that I can see whether a particular class has the fields that I need. I can't find any way of doing this in the RubyMine IDE. Is there any easy way or am I misunderstanding the way that dynamic languages work? The only way that I have found so far is by looking at the underlying database tables.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at schema.rb under the db folder.